# Configuring, saving and publishing Map?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-flex-api, flex, publishing

I'm trying to make a Flex application where there's going to be 2 main users [Administrator,User] The Administrator can add figures to the map, like polygons, or circles to remark the ratio of some locations, and also notations.
Ex. Mappoint in California, other in Washington, Other in New York etc. Then the Administrator can draw circles in the locations and add notations like " secure zone X km" 
And I want the user can see that map with that last modification but he cannot modify, only watch the map the circles and notes that the admin added previously.

I already code something with the code examples from the FLEX API page, but I can't find an example of making a map, configure it, save it, publish and get it later.

Do I need credits from ArcGIS?

Does anybody have a an example, link or something more helpful than drowning in the internet ?

Answer (score 1):

You could create two applications that both access the feature service. Have one flex application allow editing, and give that URL to the editor user. Have the other flex application be 'read only' and give that to the other user. You could also password protect the editor flex application to ensure the read-only user (or others) cannot make edits.